# Background color change on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my markup structure:

```
<div class="authentication">
  <div class="form-inputs"></div>
</div>
```

I wanted that on page load the color of authentication slides down from top-bottom.
The color is initially white and blue should slide down from the top. (like the header color fills the body).

I tried this :

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.authentication').animate({backgroundColor: '#4BC5DA'}, 3000);
  });
</script>
```

But it has a fade in effect :(

After the color change i need the "form-inputs" should fade in ... i know i need to chain the actions but im not exactly getting it.

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/29eg7/

Comment: Thanks for laying the foundation ...this is brilliant :) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dynamic overlay with a [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) animation and then fade the form when the animation completes using the callback argument:

```
$blue = $('<div>').css({
    background: 'blue',
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    top: '0',
    display: 'none'
}).appendTo('.authentication').slideDown('slow', function(){
    $('.form-inputs').fadeIn();
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/29eg7/)**

If you want a "smoother" animation then look into jQuery UI's [easing functions](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/), you can use any of them as a parameter in `slideDown()` (of course for that you need include jQuery UI to your project) or you can combine the slide effect with a fade effect, example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/29eg7/2/)

Comment: Thanks for a pleasant explanation and an elegant solution :) ... could you tell me how i can add slight delay to the form appearance ? ...

Comment: @SkyKOG for a delay you can use `$('.form-inputs').delay(2000).fadeIn();` or if you just want to control the fadeIn duration you can add a parameter like `fadeIn(2000)`

Answer (score 2):

From [jquery animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

> All animated properties should be animated to a *single numeric value*, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, `width`, `height`, or `left` can be animated but `background-color` cannot be, unless the [jQuery.Color()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin is used). Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units `em` and `%` can be specified where applicable.

**Updated** (*Using css*)

```
.authentication {
    width: 100%;
}
body:hover .authentication{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #4BC5DA;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 3s ease, height 3s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-color 3s ease, height 3s ease;
    -o-transition: background-color 3s ease, height 3s ease;
    -ms-transition: background-color 3s ease, height 3s ease;
    transition: background-color 3s ease, height 3s ease;
}
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PGrcf/1/)

The above fiddle has a drawback that it will repeat showing the slide effect whenever you move your cursor out of the window and hover again. (*which you can set using javascript/jquery*).

If you want to go with jquery then check [koala_dev's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606648/background-color-change-on-page-load#comment27386743_18606648) above.

Comment: This appears as a really elegant effect ... i really love this ... i tried combining with koala's js implementation ... but i have two issues ... the form dosent fade in and still the effect is fade-in and not dropdown ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this woking fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Z3Ts7/5/

```
<style>
.authentication{position:absolute;width:400px;height:300px;border:1px #c0c0c0 solid;overflow:hidden;}
.back{position:absolute;z-index:0;height:0%;width:100%;background-color:#53a2fa;}
#form{position:absolute;z-index:1;width:100%;height:100%;display:none;}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function down(ids){
var speed = 10;
var ele = document.getElementById(ids);
var height = parseInt(ele.style.height || ele.offsetHeight);
height = (height + 2);
ele.style.height = height+'%';
if(height<100)
setTimeout(function(){down(ids);},speed)
else
{
    $('#form').fadeIn(); //or do whatever you want
    return;
}
}
 </script>
<body>
 <div class="authentication">
    <div class="back" id="backs"></div>
    <div class="form-inputs" id="form">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
down('backs');
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much ... this works good ...but due to heavy use of js ... is causing choppy performance at high speed values eg:100

Comment: greater the value of speed, it will slide slow, to make it fast reduce it

Comment: Im talking about the smoothness of the transition :) http://jsfiddle.net/PGrcf/1/ ....see the smoothness in this ...

Comment: the fasetest is 1, i can see it smotthly in my PC