# How can I draw in gridlines in the background of a website after loading?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, linear-gradients, gridlines

I'm trying to animate the background of my website, which has a solid background, and then I want to "sketch" gridlines over it. Right now I have the background drawn as such:

```
background-color: #269;
background-image: linear-gradient(@light-grey 2px, transparent 2px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, @light-grey 2px, transparent 2px),
    linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .3) 1px, transparent 1px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3) 1px, transparent 1px);
background-size: 100px 100px, 100px 100px, 20px 20px, 20px 20px;
background-position: -2px -2px, -2px -2px, -1px -1px, -1px -1px;
```

I want it to be like this, except I want the linear-gradients to load one-by-one and make them look sketched in if possible.

I tried looking at this code:
[Background color change on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606648/background-color-change-on-page-load)

And it seemed sort of along the tracks of what I'm trying to do, but I don't want the whole background to change, I only want to draw in the grid.

I also think I may need to use this to make it draw in after the page loads:
[JavaScript that executes after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load?rq=1)

Should I be assigning IDs to the linear-gradients and calling them in a Javascript function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to accomplish this doesn't involve JavaScript at all.

Instead, it uses a CSS pseudo element containing only the grid line portion of the background, and animates it as it stretches from a size of `0px * 0px` to `100% * 100%`.

The basic gist of the code is shown below (updated to display behind div content):

```
div {
  /* Background color code is placed here */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

div::before {
  /* Grid background code is placed here */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  content: " ";
  animation: gridWipe 1s linear;
}

@keyframes gridWipe {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }

  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

To see this in action, take a look at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/e03yofrt/13/).

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! But now it seems to be pushing the text out of the way as the grid wipes. How can I make the text above the animation stay in the same spot? For example if you add <p>"Test"</p> to the div in the JSFiddle you provided, it gets pushed out as the grid wipes.

Comment: Fixed. The `::before` pseudo element can be attached to the top left corner of the `div` by setting `position: relative;` on the div, `position: absolute;` on the pseudo element, and the using `top`, `left`, and `z-index` attributes to move and stack both elements. I've updated my answer and the JSFiddle to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Works great!

Answer (score 2):

You can create your background differently using `repeating-linear-gradient` then animate `background-size` like below:

```css
div.box {
  background-image: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent,transparent 98px,lightGray 98px,lightGray 100px),
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right, transparent,transparent 98px,lightGray 98px,lightGray 100px),
    
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent ,transparent 19px,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 19px,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 20px),
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right, transparent ,transparent 19px,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 19px,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 20px);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-color: #269;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  animation:gridWipe 3s linear;
}

@keyframes gridWipe {
  0% {
    background-size:0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-size:100% 100%;
  }

}

p {
  background: rgba(255,255,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

You can also consider some CSS variable to optimize your code:

```css
div.box {
  --l_b:2px; /*width of the big line*/
  --l_s:1px; /*width of the small line*/
  --d_b:100px; /*distance between big lines*/
  --d_s:20px; /*distance between small lines*/

  --c1:transparent,transparent calc(var(--d_b) - var(--l_b)),lightGray calc(var(--d_b) - var(--l_b)),lightGray var(--d_b);
  --c2:transparent,transparent calc(var(--d_s) - var(--l_s)),rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) calc(var(--d_s) - var(--l_s)),rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) var(--d_s);
  
  background-image: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,var(--c1)),
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right, var(--c1)),
    
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,var(--c2)),
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right, var(--c2));
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-color: #269;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  animation:gridWipe 3s linear;
}

@keyframes gridWipe {
  0% {
    background-size:0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-size:100% 100%;
  }

}

p {
  background: rgba(255,255,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```